# MySQL - expensive subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have this query that was taking 13 seconds to run, consistently:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Counter 
FROM Groups_Users gu 
JOIN Groups g ON gu.GroupID = g.GroupID 
WHERE (
    (gu.UserID = 3 AND gu.IsAdmin = 1 AND g.GroupID = 395) 
    OR g.OrganizationID IN ( 
        SELECT OrganizationID FROM Organizations_Users WHERE UserID = 3 AND IsAdmin = 1 ) 
)
```

After adding indexes to Groups_Users and Organization_Users, it went to less than 1 second. So, problem solved, except that I expect the number of records in these 2 tables to grow a lot. And I'm wondering if my subselect and/or join is inefficient and could be made better. Maybe at some point the performance will degrade again when the record count goes from 8,000 to 100,000 because the subselect is inefficient.

Any ideas on making this query better?

Comment: an alternative is to look at exists... IN can be a LOT slower than EXISTS

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but I'm not practiced with EXISTS. This doesn't work: "OR g.OrganizationID EXISTS ( " -- what would be the correct syntax, given my query above?

Comment: `OR EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Organizations_Users ou WHERE ou.UserID = 3 AND ou.IsAdmin = 1 AND ou.organizationID = g.organizationid)`

Comment: i'll put it as an answer so you can see it formatted. test it and see how it performs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Counter 
FROM Groups_Users gu 
JOIN Groups g ON gu.GroupID = g.GroupID 
WHERE
(   
    (    gu.UserID = 3 
     AND gu.IsAdmin = 1 
     AND g.GroupID = 395
    ) 
    OR EXISTS 
        (   SELECT 1 
            FROM Organizations_Users ou 
            WHERE ou.UserID = 3 
              AND ou.IsAdmin = 1 
              AND ou.organizationid = g.organizationid
        ) 
)
```

basically you say select 1 where these conditions are met.. if they are true then the exists query is true and it will include it. so all you have to do is add `AND ou.organizationid = g.organizationid` to the subquery and you're good to go

Comment: @SweatCoder my pleasure :) +1 reciprocated!